# Simplifying A State Machine To Reduce Logic Levels and Meet Timing

Tags: vhdl, timing

My design at the moment isn't meeting timing. I've tried putting it on a slower clock and pipelining the inputs/outputs. The problem is always the same - too many levels of logic. Have any of you got any tips on making this logic more clock friendly?

```
signal ctr : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
signal sig_bit_shift : std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);

begin

process(clk_p)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk_p) then
        if rst_i = '1' or nuke = '1' then
            ctr <= (others => '0'); 
            state <= ST_IDLE;
        elsif unsigned(event_settings) < 1 then -- disables
            state <= ST_IDLE;
        elsif unsigned(event_settings) = 1 then -- always on
            state <= ST_ENABLE;    
        else
            case state is
            when ST_IDLE =>
                if ctr = (unsigned(event)-2) then                     
                    state <= ST_ENABLE;
                elsif unsigned(ctr) = 1 and sig = '0' then --catches first word
                    state <= ST_ENABLE;                       
                elsif sig = '1' then
                    ctr <= ctr + 1;
                end if;
            when ST_ENABLE =>
                if s_sig = '1' then
                    state <= ST_IDLE;
                    if unsigned(s_evt) > 1 then
                        ctr <= (others => '0');
                    end if;
                end if;
            end case;
        end if;
    end if; 
end process;
```

UPDATE:

```
process(clk_p)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk_p) then
        if rst_i = '1' or nuke = '1' then
            ctr <= x"00" & "10"; 
            state <= ST_IDLE;
        elsif settings = '1' then
            case state is
            when ST_IDLE =>
                if ctr = (unsigned(event)) then                     
                    state <= ST_ENABLE;
                elsif unsigned(ctr) = 1 and sig = '0' then --catches first word -- this is the part which when added, fails timing
                    state <= ST_ENABLE;                       
                elsif sig = '1' then
                    ctr <= ctr + 1;
                end if;
            when ST_ENABLE =>
                if s_sig = '1' then
                    state <= ST_IDLE;
                    if unsigned(s_evt) > 1 then
                        ctr <= X"00" & "10";
                    end if;
                end if;
            end case;
        end if;
    end if; 
end process;
```

I think too it's slowed down by where the signal comes from:

```
sig <= sig_token when unsigned(SIG_DELAY) < 1 else (sig_bit_shift(to_integer(unsigned(SIG_DELAY)-1)));

process(clk_p) -- delays sig
begin
    if rising_edge(clk_p) then
        if rst = '1' then
            sig_bit_shift <= (others => '0');
        else
            sig_bit_shift <= l1a_bit_shift(sig_bit_shift'high-1 downto 0) & sig_token;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

UPDATE 2 :

Seems like half the routing went into the above delay so i'm going to try and fix with this:

```
signal sig_del_en : std_logic;
signal sig_del_sel : integer; 

begin
process(clk_p)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk_p) then
        if unsigned(SIG_DELAY) = 0 then
            sig_del_en <= '0';
        else
            sig_del_en <= '1';
        end if;
        sig_del_sel <= to_integer(unsigned(SIG_DELAY)-1);
    end if;
end process;

   sig <= sig_token when sig_del_en = '0' else (sig_bit_shift(sig_del_sel));
```

Comment: What is the desired frequency? Can you post the failing path? How many bits have: ctr, event_settings, event and s_evt?

Comment: The slowest part is likely to be `if ctr = (unsigned(event)-2) then` which serialises a subtraction and a comparison. You could maintain a separate signal always ctr + 2 (registered) to shorten this path. But as Paebbels is hinting there is probably something else wrong (like declaring ctr with unnecessarily many bits).

Comment: Or more directly, please show the declarations for the signals used in this process. Show how they are assigned. Also what is the clock rate?

Comment: Clock rate is 40 MHz. I'll add some more information about the signals used once I've built with a reduced counter size and using some techniques from the method explained by Morten.

Comment: And the timing endpoint fail is that counter...

Comment: Also some of these driving signals are coming from a bitshift which I think complicates the logic

Comment: You were right Brian, that was the slowest part. I tried to correct for it but it still fails timing when that part is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the "slow" operations are array `=` which requires compare over all bits in the argument, and `<` and `>` which requires subtraction over all bits in the argument.  So you may improve timing in a cycle, if there is sufficient time in the previous cycle to generate the compare result up front as a `std_logic`.  It may be relevant for these:

- `unsigned(event_settings) < 1`
- `unsigned(event_settings) = 1`
- `ctr = (unsigned(event)-2)`
- `unsigned(ctr) = 1`
- `unsigned(s_evt) > 1`

The code to generate the different `std_logic` values depends on the way the related signal is generated, but an example can be:

```
process (clk) is
  variable event_settings_v : event_settings'range;
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    ...
    event_settings_v := ... code for generating event_settings;  -- Variable with value
    event_settings <= event_settings_v;  -- Signal drive from variable
    if unsigned(event_settings_v) < 1 then
      unsigned_event_settings_tl_1 <= '1';
    else
      unsigned_event_settings_tl_1 <= '0';
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

The code `unsigned(event_settings) < 1` in the state machine can then be changed to `unsigned_event_settings_tl_1 = '1'`, which may improve timing if this compare is in the critical path.

Using the asynchronous reset typically available on the the flip-flop for `rst_i = '1'` may also improve timing, since it removes logic from the synchronous part.  It is unlikely to give a significant improvement, but it's typically a good design practice in order to maximize the time for synchronous logic.  The asynchronous reset is used through coding style like:

```
process (rst_i, clk_p) is
begin
  if rst_i = '1' then
    ... Apply asynchronous reset value to signals
  elsif rising_edge(clk_p) then
    ... Synchronous update of signals
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by using the asynchronous reset?

Comment: Added code example to question; see also [google asynchronous reset  flip flop](https://www.google.dk/#q=asynchronous+reset++flip+flop).

Comment: Looking at the clock timing report, it seems like it fails as it has to go through that delay I've added into my question (which is roughly half of the routing apparently). So I'm building now with an adapted version. Fingers crossed.